# CF + email with confirmation link

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm working on Wordpress with the plugin contact form 7. I need to create a contact form where the user will:

1. insert his info (name, phone, address, etc…);
2. when clicking “submit” he will receive an email (to avoid someone else that might insert his data) with a confirmation link;
3. when clicking that link in the email, the info submitted in the CF will be then sent to the website owner.

The form itself is no issue, but points 2 and 3 I’m having some trouble figuring them out…

Comment: share some code what you have tried

Comment: So far i've only set up the form with its fields. 
Meanwhile i've found this plugin: https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/6516451 that may do what i need. Sadly, I'm not a php coder (yet) so i don't know how to exactly integrate this plugin with the form